# Salesforce - How can I run testMethods with specific profile permissions?

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce

We have a piece of code that is meant to run from the Public Site's user.

Currently, the testMethods run as the standard test user, and the code works fine. However, the funcionality fails on the site, requesting user authentication before running the code (which shouldn't, since the user won't have Salesforce credentials).

Is there a way that we can make the testMethods run as the site's guest user, or a similar profile? Take in mind that we cannot know the profile's name beforehand, and that the profile might not even exist when the tests are run.

Answer (score 0):

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='MyProfile']; 

User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

System.runAs(u) 
{
        System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a user with a specific profile or permission set in question. This you can do in a prior method. Use @isTest for that method as well.

Then use Run As System.runAs(u) functionality to run the method as that user.

Visit https://nonitechsolutions.blogspot.com/2021/06/salesforce-enable-guest-user-on-your.html

Answer (score -1):

Salesforce has the System.runas method to run tests as a certain user. If you don't know the profile name ahead of time I assume you are doing this in a managed package or something similar.

You could do something like the following sample from the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_testing_tools_runas.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

```
public class TestRunAs {
   public static testMethod void testRunAs() {
      User u;
      u = [select ID from user where communitynickname = :yoursitename]


      System.runAs(u) {
      // The following code runs as user 'u'  

      System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
      System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); }
```

}
}

Comment: This sounds to be exactly what we need. But what if I don't know the site's name? Or should I create a site on my org just to test? (I think it's bad practice to rely on existing data for testing).

Comment: You could query the Site Sobject to get the name.